# I cant get my index page to show on my cloudways symfony app

Tags: php, html, symfony4, cloudways

I use CloudWays hosting for my web app. I am trying to get my index page to work. Example: www.mysite.com or www.mysite.com to point to my index or home page. I have set up the following controller after running `composer require annotations`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{

     /**
      * @Route("/", name="main")
      */

    public function index()
    {

        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', ['controller_name' => 'HomeController',]);

    }
}
```

I followed the official Symfony 4 documentation for routing which defines this example code(https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing.html):

```
// src/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Matches /blog exactly
     *
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog_list")
     */
    public function list()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
/projectfolder
---- /public_html
     ---- /bin
          /config
          ----/dev
              framework.yaml
          annotations.yaml
          /public
          ----/assets
              /css
              /js
              .htaccess
              index.php
          /src
          ----/Controller
              ----HomeController.php
              Kernal.php
          /templates
          ----/main
              ----index.html.twig
              base.html.twig
          /var
          /vendor
          .env
          .swp
           composer.json
           composer.lock
           symfony.lock
```

When I enter the url www.mysite.com I get a 403 Forbidden error.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.mysite.om Port 80
```

When I enter the url www.mysite.com/public it works and displays my site perfectly.

How can i fix this issue so my index is at www.mysite.com and not www.mysite.com/public

Google Domains Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. In order to fix my issue I needed to do the following:

Step 1) Navigate to the Cloudways server application settings panel.

[image]

Step 2) Change webroot to wherever your public files are located in your project.

[image]

If you do not know where your public files are located you can find out by connecting to the apache server through the provided terminal and using the `cd` command to navigate to the directory. Or connect with an ftps connection to navigate to the needed directory.

After doing this `www.mysite.com` should bring you to your `index/home page`. After researching as to why this happens I found out that the `index.php` is one layer down from what my root folder was at first. In order to fix this I needed to bring my root folder to the correct layer where `index.php` was located.

Answer (score 0):

Since CloudWays seems to be a shared hosting site that uses `Apache server` you may need an `Apache pack`. Run command `composer require symfony/apache-pack` in your console and upload your project files again to see if it helped.

Comment: I got it to work. In the end I have public_html as my root but I need to have public_html/public as root.